# Does the verb 'skid' take an object?

Tags: grammar

Does the verb “skid” take an object? So is it OK to say:

> He skidded his car on the road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* offers precisely that example:

> **skid** [intrans.]: (of a vehicle) slide, typically sideways or obliquely, on slippery ground or as a result of stopping or turning too quickly.
>
> **• [trans.] cause to skid: *he skidded his car*.**

So: yes.

Answer (score 2):

"Skid" may be a transitive (cause to skid) or an intransitive verb.  When it is intransitive, no object is required.  E.g., These tires never skid in the rain.